# Apache Axis: How to add complex parameter

Tags: java, xml, soap, axis

I'm trying to send request using apache and pass a nested parameter to it.

What i need is something like below but don't know how to call `javax.xml.rpc.Call.addParameter` to put `Param1` and `Param2` in `ParentType`.

```
...
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ActionX>
        <ParentType>
            <Param1>Val1</Param1>
            <Param2>Val2</Param2>
        </ParentType>
    </ActionX>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
...
```

WDSL for `ActionX` and `ParentType` is like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions>
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:element name="ActionX">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="pt" type="q1:ParentType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema>
        <xs:complexType name="ParentType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Param1" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Param2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="ParentType" type="tns:ParentType"/>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generate class files from these wsdl you would find suitable methods. Please explain how you are invoking the web service

Comment: I just use `javax.xml.rpc.Call.invoke` method. `addParameter`, `setReturnType`, etc then `invoke`. Like sample here: http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Basics_-_Getting_Started